# Check the occurrence of the first character in multiple files using SED,AWK or GREP

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

Suppose I have file which goes like this :

```
      a  void measure()    
         {

      a  GPIOPinTypeADC(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7); // Pin assignment
         ADCSequenceConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 3, ADC_TRIGGER_PROCESSOR, 0);
         appended line for demonstration
         ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 3, 0, ADC_CTL_CH0 | ADC_CTL_IE |ADC_CTL_END);
         ADCSequenceEnable(ADC0_BASE, 3);//sample sequence 3 is enabled.
         ADCIntClear(ADC0_BASE, 3);   // Clear the interrupt status flag.
         }
```

Can I use `SED` or `AWK`  to output true if and only if `a` is prepended to the first coloum with space as the delimiter . The first character is always `a` otherwise space .

As of now I use `GREP` :

```
    if grep -q "^a" file.c; then
       echo "The file is prepended"
       else
       echo "the file is clean"
   fi
```

I have several functions like the first one above in separate files and want to categorise it based on the prepended `a` .

Is it possible to do this easily and over multiple files using `GREP` itself .I would really prefer a `SED` or `AWK` alternative avoiding the use of the `if` construct for hundreds to come .

Suggestions or better algorithms are always welcome :)

Comment: First, it's `grep` and not `GREP`, secondly I presume you mean "prepended" (or prefixed) and not "appended." Thirdly, do you mean "if any line in the file has an 'a' as the first character" it should report true, otherwise false? What's wrong with using your `if` statement (apart from its obvious bug)? What Are You Doing?

Comment: @Sorpigal My bad , It is prepended ! Changed now .

Comment: @Sorpigal I want to extend this for multiple files in the same directory

Comment: Incidentally, your current `if` statement should have been written like this: `if grep ^a file.c 1>/dev/null 2>&1` to avoid the useless use of `cat`, but there's no point in generating output only to throw it away so you could also have just said `if grep -q ^a file.c`, as I did in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and especially for  explaining why , your code works great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very difficult to tell what you're asking, but it sounds like you might want this

```
grep -q ^a file.c && echo 'The file is appended' || echo 'the file is clean'
```

Or perhaps you really want this:

```
grep -L ^a *.c
```

Each resulting file name being an "appended" file.

For multiple files you could do it this way

```
for file in *.c ; do
   grep -q '^a ' file.c && echo 'The file is appended' || echo 'the file is clean'
done
```

For multiple files recursively, try

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep -q '^a ' {} \; -print
```

Although to get the 'correct' output you'd need more work.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `cat`?
You can specify as many files as you wish with `grep`, `sed` or `awk`, but I am unclear as to if you want 'True' for each file, for tru if any of the files contain this pattern.  Let's assume the former:

```
awk '/^a /{print FILENAME "is True"}' 'list-of-files'
```

Comment: @kev:  There is nothing in the question to indicate that it only applies to the first line, is there?  The eample `grep` does not indicate that either.

Comment: @cdarke Yes ,Starting from the first line till the end of the file :)

Comment: @cdarke Sorry ,didnt see your question : true for each good file .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
awk 'FNR==1&&($1=="a") {printf "The file %s is prepended\n",FILENAME}' *.c
```